Defining the probability space for rolling a die infinitely many times
Say we want to know the probability that when we roll a dice infinitely many times, we get 6 infinitely often. Intuitively the answer is $1$, but how do we construct a probability space to model this?
The natural sample space is $\Omega = \{ 1, \dots, 6\}^{\mathbb N}$, i.e. the set of sequences taking values in $\{ 1, \dots, 6\}$. Can we simply take $\mathcal F$ to be the power set of $\Omega$ and define a sensible probability measure $\mathbb P$ (this measure, if it exists, would have to assign probability zero to any countable subset of $\Omega$)? How would we construct $\mathbb P$ to have the properties we want (e.g. independence between rolls)?

Think of it as $[0,1]$ with the uniform distribution.  The map being "create the base $6$ decimal corresponding to the toss sequence, pretending the faces were ${0, \cdots 5}$."   See this question for a relevant duplicate.

It is enough to prove that the probability is $1$ that we eventually throw a $6$. Then , we can repeat this experiment over and over again and will always have success. Therefore , the probability for infinite many sixes must be $1$.

@lulu Thank you, this is helpful. I guess if we insist on using ${1, \dots, 6}^{\mathbb N}$ as the sample space, we can construct the bijection $f: [0, 1] \to {1, \dots, 6}^{\mathbb N}$ appropriately, then take $\mathcal F = f(\mathcal B([0, 1]))$ and $\mathbb P(A) = \mu(f^{-1}(A))$, where $\mathcal B$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra and $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure.

Yes, exactly.  In practice, of course, one normally looks at finite sequences with limits.

@lulu I think there may be a slight caveat in this argument though, in that the base-6 expansion of a number in $[0, 1]$ may not be unique. I have no doubt that there is a bijection between the two sets, but something like independence between rolls seems to rely on us mapping $(a_1, a_2, \dots) \mapsto 0.a_1 a_2 \dots$, which is actually not a bijection.

Yeah, don't worry about sets of measure $0$.

NO, do not use the power set.

To be sure:  in practice, what one means is a statement of the form "Given any $(M, \epsilon)$, there exists an $N$ such that, if $n≥N$, the probability that a toss sequence of length $n$ will show fewer than $M$ of the desired face is $<\epsilon$."  And that is easily shown.

The trick of using base-$6$ expansions on $[0, 1]$ in the comments is nice but you might find it a little inelegant, since after all the problem statement makes no reference to real numbers, and there is this non-uniqueness issue (it doesn't matter since it does not affect the probability of anything - we only have "non-uniqueness up to a set of measure zero" - but I think it's a little conceptually unsatisfying).
Alternatively there is a general construction of the countable product of probability measures, which is relatively simple in this case. The measurable sets are taken to be the cylinder $\sigma$-algebra. This is just saying the measurable sets are generated by the events "the first $n$ dice rolls have these exact values." The probability measure is determined by what it does to these events and those probabilities should be the obvious thing (specifying the first $n$ dice rolls gives an event of probability $\frac{1}{6^n}$). This measure can be thought of as Haar measure on the product of infinitely many copies of the finite cyclic group $\mathbb{Z}/6$.
If you believe that this all works out then the desired statement follows by the second Borel-Cantelli lemma.

Also we cannot take the measurable sets to be the full power set, because this runs into the exact same issues as over $\mathbb{R}$ with the Vitali set and so forth.
